# AS3: Showing bufferlength of NetStream

Tags: actionscript-3, buffer, netstream

I am trying to show the buffered amount of a video that is playing. I am using netstream.bufferLength to do this and it kinda seems to be right. Exept from the fact that it is almost constantly the same amount that is buffered. This can't be right?

I want it to be like youtube where you can press pause and the buffer will continue to rise. When I click pause it just stays the same..

Anybody knows how to show buffer length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are getting confused between buffer which is a preloaded section of content that loads just infront of the current playcode, thus being a comparason to teh timecode you are at and the availablilty of instant playing and caching a loaded file which puts the whole file into temporary memory, so allowing for the loading as you described.

you can find the total loaded data (percentage) by using `netstream.bytesLoaded / netstream.bytesTotal;`

Comment: I have tried that too, but that is constantly at 100%. Can that be right?

Comment: Ahh! Never mind! It works perfectly when the movie isnt already loaded. Stupid me :)

Thank you so much :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the right answer. For streaming content - 
bytesLoaded and bytesTotal are always 0.
I'm looking for  a way to do it as well. While @shortstick definition of buffering is accurate - I think you actually do need/can to use that information to show buffering state. You can use NetStream.Buffer.Empty & NetStream.Buffer.Full to know when it's buffering...

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure what you want is: NetStream.time + NetStream.bufferLength. As @shortstick mentioned - the buffer is related to the current play-position - you can regard the amount of time that was played as "already-buffered-and-used" - so the total amount of "buffered content" is:

```
NetStream.time + NetStream.bufferLength
```

I've used this, with good results.